# Check if a string substitution rule will ever generate another string

Tags: algorithm

Not homework.

Given two strings S and T of same length.
Given a set of replacement rules, that find substring A in S and replace it with string B.
A and B have the same length.

Is there a sequence of rule application, such that it make string S into string T?

Example:
We have replacement rules

```
cat->dog
dog->cut
```

we have string
S1:awesomecat and S2:awesomecut

A sequence of replacement can be

```
awesomecat 
awesomedog cat->dog
awesomecut dog->cut
```

That's a easy example, it's possible there are rules like this.

```
cat->dog
ate->dog
dog->cat
```

I believe there is no better way to answer this than try every single rule in every single state. Which would be exponential time. But I don't know if there are better solutions to it.

Comment: @ChristopheD It's much harder than edit distance metrics. Edit distance is about editing one character at a time, but here the rules can have overlaps.

Comment: Mmm, interesting. It seems to me to be suited to some "genetic" algorithm style. I think, as you say, it's not possible aside from mapping all possile transforms. It actually reminds me a lot of the little toy languages in Hofstadters "Godel Escher Bach" (i.e. transformation rules from one to the other looking for a specific string).

Comment: The simple algorithm is worse than exponential time: There is a possibly infinite number of reachable strings, so you'll never know when to stop.

Comment: @interjay there is only finite number of reachable strings, because any replacement rule doesn't change the length of the string. So there are at most (possible characters)^(length of the string) reachable strings. I think the more general problem, where replacement rules can change the length of the string, is undecidable(seems similar to PCP)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it said A and B have the same length.

Comment: @Mggcl - can you provide more examples of string substitution rules?  Are they always going to all be of the same length?  Or always three letters?  What kind of original/starting strings will you be having?

Comment: Everything that fit the criteria is possible. This is a very general problem. I asked the same question in mathoverflow but in ways mathematician understood it. In fact, now I think this problem might be a research level problem. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28683/computational-complexity-of-the-word-problem-for-semi-thue-systems-with-certain-r

Comment: Ah, so this isn't actually a problem for an immediate programming solution; just an abstract/theoretical one.

Comment: @Justin I am implementing a program to do this, I don't know if there is any better algorithm than brute force search. thus I asked it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read [Godel, Escher, Bach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) =)  It discusses exactly what you are describing here.

In conclusion, one solution proposed is to find an [**invariant**](http://bit.ly/wxSPO) to your system: a property that, if true at the start of the manipulations, **must in all cases** also be true at the end of your manipulations.

If your first string possess that invariant, and your ending string does not, then your substitution rule will *never* generate the second string.

Your invariant rule can be more powerful...for example, it can be an **if and only if** relationship (an invariant is true in the end step if and only if it is true at the first step), so you can prove that the end string is unreachable if there is an invariant that is not true in the first string.  Note that these if and only if relationships follow automatically from the standard if relationships if all of your rules work both way (you can apply them backwards and forwards)

For example, here is a possible invariant in your first system:

- All contiguous strings not containing the contiguous string combination 'cat' or 'dog' within them must also be present at the end state

Given that invariant rule, it is straightforward to provide a decision formula to decide whether or not a string is possible given a starting string.

---

*append*

I hope you don't mind if I adopt Hofstadter's terms, in that:

- A given, starting string will be called an 'axiom'
- Axioms may be acted on by a set of rules
- Any string of letters is called a 'theorem'; a string of letters that can be produced by the rules from the given axioms is called a 'valid theorem'

So, your question moves from "can X produce Y?" to "is Y a valid theorem, derivable from X?"

So, let's approach your string substitution problem from a more general terms.  We will call `A` the ordered set of all substituted strings, and `A` the ordered set of all substituting strings.  Therefore, here we have our single generalized rule:

```
"xA[n]y" => "xB[n]y"
```

This says, "If ever we see a theorem with a string in set `A`, surrounded by strings `x` and `y`, then we may derive, also, `xB[n]y`, where `B[n]` is the corresponding substituting string.

Let's find some invariants, that are true, **regardless of what is in sets `A` and `B`**.

- As a consequence of your substituting strings always being the same length as their substituted string, *any letter in an axiom that is not found in in `A` must not move*

For example, if we have axiom `abcdea`, and ruleset `A=["cd",de"]`, it's easy to see that the letters a and b are not found in `A`.  Therefore, we can say that all theorems in this system must be of the form `ab##a`.  This gives us a rule to find what is **not** a theorem.

However, for very long sets `A`, this might not help us that much, for `A` might conceivably use all letters.

Let's try making this more useful...

- Any letter at the *end* of an axiom, that is not at the end of a string in `A`, cannot move.  The same can be said for any letter at the *beginning* of an axiom, that is not at the beginning of a string in `A`.

Let's say we have `A=["dog","cat","ton"]`, any if an axiom ends in any letter *that is not g, t, or c*, *all derivable theorems **must*** also end in the same letter.  If an axiom begins with any letter *not d, c, or t*, all derivable theorems **must** also begin with the same letter, as well.

This is somewhat more useful, because for any `A` with a size < 26, you will have letters that they do not end or begin with.  However, it becomes a lot less likely for your axioms to begin or end with those specific letters.

However, we find that we can extend this further:

- Any continuous string of letters at the beginning of an axiom that is not a continuous string at the beginning of a string in `A` must not move; the same for a continuous string at the end of an axiom that is not a continuous string at the end of a string in `A`.

We'll find that this is a lot more useful!  `A` has to be at least 26^n elements large for us to dismiss this invariant as useless.

Now, note, we can go backwards, too!  That is, we can say:

- Any continuous string of letters at the beginning of a theory that is not a continuous string at the beginning of a string in `B` must also be there in all axioms; the same for a continuous string at the end of a theorem that is not a continuous string at the end of a string in `B`.

With those rules, I've assembled a [decision tree](http://pastie.org/1009637) for figuring out which cases we have locked, and which cases are indeterminable.  You'll notice that we only have two such indeterminable cases.

Now all that's left is to find an invariant of the those two cases.  However, we can notice one thing:

- An invariant rule to `CASE 2` can also be applied to `CASE 1`, with the leading/trailing "not-in-A/B" strings ignored

That is, if you have `A=["cat","dog"],B=["dog","cut"]`, and axiom-theorem `boabcdut` `boablmut`, then any invariant rules you have that you can apply to `CASE 2`'s can also be applied to `cdut => mlut`, with the non-matching leading string `boab` ignored.  This simplifies things considerably.

So, we've basically resolved both undetermined case to one case; let's see what else we can analyze...

...another time.  I'll get back to this in a bit.

Comment: That is true. But computers can't come up with invariants by themselves :(

Comment: Ah, you were looking for an algorithm, without any human logic involved; all computerthinkings.  Hm.  I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer, since the problem is NP(the general case), therefore finding invariants are the best idea if one can know more about the input.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not a complete solution; however, it *does* provide a mechanism for reducing the problem to a smaller one.  I'll try to add more heuristics soon; this problem has really fascinated me.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily map this problem to a directed graph in which all rules are directed paths from one node to another.

Upon receiving inputs *A* and *B*, check the diff between them, and see if you have a path along the graph that yields expected result.

Comment: How does the diff help? It's the same as what it was in my post, it still have to check the entire search space, which is exponential time relative to the amount of rules and the length of the 2 strings.